# Socket.io and offline people in android

Tags: android, node.js, socket.io

I was wondering about something using socket.io and android.

I realized a little chat application between a webpage and an android app. The problem is when I need to  chat with the android app when the device doesn't have a network connection.

Is it possible to manage this with socket.io in nodejs ? In fact, I realized that it takes 1-2 mns to node to know that the user lost the connexion.. So the server tries to send but cant. And it's lost.

Do you have an idea ?

Comment: you can get acc from client to received message or not

Comment: There's no way to manage a cache with nodejs, if he cant send the message ?

Comment: in android you can `emit` another method in response method (`on`) that get messaged from server, send `id` of message to server into `JSON`

Comment: Yes I know that. But I need to make less exchange as possible. I m sure it exists something better :O

Comment: i think another parameter sends via socket i don't work with that but you can search about that, maybe that help you

Comment: try to change heartbeat interval and timeout values